# Subgroup of finite index in the derived subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G be a group such that G' has a normal subgroup of finite index H. There exists a subgroup of finite index in G whose derived subgroup is contained into H?

Comment: No, $G'$ can be finite but contained in every finite index subgroup. An example is given by the central product of infinitely many nonabelian groups of order $p^3$, for some fixed prime $p$ (central product meaning the restricted direct product, identifying all centers).

Comment: You could ask whether it is true when $G$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I guess if $G$ is finitely generated and moreover $H$ is normal in $G$ (not merely in $G'$), then it's true, but that feels like a pretty severe extra assumption.